# PHP populate images

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm looking to take a folder worth of images and have php determine their size and then write their code depending on whether the width or height is higher.

```
<?php

    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        $filename = $i.".png";
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        if($width > $height)
        {
            echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="' .$width. '" height="75px" />';
            break;
        }
        elseif ($height > $width)
        {
            echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="75px" height="' .$height. '" />';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="' .$width. '" height="' .$height. '" />';
            break;
        }
    }

?>
```

The problem is, is that it writes the code after the "if" statement. I'm not sure if I'm coding something incorrectly. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Cheers

Comment: What's with the `break` statements? They will exit your loop after the first iteration, and are not needed in an `if/else` chain as they are needed in a `switch`.

Comment: What do you mean "after the "if" statement". There is only one if statement so how can it write any code?

Comment: The `break;` statements are breaking your code after the first iteration, you don't need them with if/else/elseif statements. The break statement jumps out of a loop/switch.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `break;` statements after each if, unless you want it to  exit the for loop after only one time around the loop, which I don't think you do.

```
<?php

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    $filename = $i.".png";
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    if($width > $height){
        echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="' .$width. '" height="75px" />';
    }elseif ($height > $width){
        echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="75px" height="' .$height. '" />';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="' .$filename. '" width="' .$width. '" height="' .$height. '" />';

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't originally have the break; in there but I heard that it might understand the variable better so I gave it a shot, and that still didn't work.

Comment: Take an image from the folder, if the image has more width than height write code as such and vice versa. It will automatically list the images I have into a nice display based on width vs height.

Comment: Well, no-one will write all that code for you!  You'll have to write it the best you can and then come back here if you have any specific problems